# Fetch a df column title/header for data in a specific row satisfying a condition

Tags: python

I have one hot encoded a text data so that I looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to write code that will give me the column name for where 1 is found for respective row.

e. g.

labels = df.iloc[index, ......]

where index will go for from 0 to 32937 (for each column) and in .... I want to specify the column header for which the data == 1 is to be found. I hope it's clear what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
def fn(row):

    if row['negative'] == 1:
            return 'negative'

    elif row['neutral'] == 1:
        return 'neutral'
    
    elif row['positive'] == 1:
        return 'positive'
```

Create a function as above and use apply method:

```
train_dataset['new_col'] = train_dataset.apply(fn, axis=1)
```